# Spring XD aggregate counter timeField format

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

I am ingesting a stream of http request logs from a remote server and want to create an aggregate counter to watch the traffic.
I am getting JSON string containing field "timestamp" in SQL format:

```
{"timestamp": "2015-08-12 23:21:13", ...}
```

I have a stream called "tick" with definition:

```
time --fixedDelay=1 | script --script=Puller.groovy | json-to-tuple | null
```

I am creating an aggregate counter:

```
tap:stream:tick.json-to-tuple > aggregate-counter --name=lcnt --timeField=payload.timestamp
```

How can I convert the field value to the acceptable format and what format is this?

Comment: Ok, I discovered that the format is of the form: YYYY-MM-dd\HH:mm:ss.uuuZ and created a transformer script to convert to this format. But it would make sense if the aggregate counter would accept timestamp format as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, I was not paying due attention to the docs.
aggregate-counter has a dateFormat parameter with SimpleDateFormat syntax.
So, the final solution looks like that:

```
tap:stream:tick.json-to-tuple > aggregate-counter --name=lcnt --timeField=payload.timestamp --dateFormat='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
```